# Bug Reporting in an Application

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, bug-reporting

I would like a form where users can reports bugs about my application. My initial thought was  create a random gmail account hard code information about the account in to the application and mail reports to the account from where i can forward them to my email. using JavaMail. I do not want to maintain a SMTP server just the receive bugs. How do you guys do it any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you use a [bug tracking system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system) instead. This also allows you to *manage* the bugs, not just to receive them.

Comment: I agree, a complete bug tracking system can really help you manage your project better and it gives users the ability to see how stable your product is (which is usually a good thing :-)

Comment: @Topher Fangio: Yes, that's usually one of the first things I check before I commit myself to download/install/learn/use a piece of software... :)

Comment: my project is hosted in github i am using their tracking system i am more interested. in getting bugs from users.

Answer (score 3):

How about using Google Docs to [create a form](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809) that the "report bug" form can post to?

Or perhaps just open up a browser window to the URL of your bug-collecting form?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a tiny web service interface and host it with some backend database. Your application can just call the webservice to add the bug information to the database.

Or you could put a browser control on a form and call an asp/php/... page which will gather the bug data and 1) Send it to your email and/or 2) add to database and/or 3)write to a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into a bug/issue management software.  If you have a server where you can host it yourself, [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a popular open source option.  If you do not wish to host it yourself, you can use an inexpensive service like [assembla](http://www.assembla.com) to host both your issue management software and your source control system.

If you insist on rolling your own solution, you can use a web based service as a relay, but I would suggest externalizing the credentials (host, username, password).  In addition I would suggest adding a list of destination email addresses, as this will allow you to make a distribution list if it is ever needed.  By externalizing the config information, you can update the running application without having to redeploy code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), similar with Trac in many aspects. Starting with version 0.8 it supports *Ticket submission via email*.Even if this is not the recommended way to receive tickets sometime is useful - like when your clients are too lazy or refuses to use a trouble ticket system :).

Answer (score 0):

Some bug tracking systems such as Jira provide RPC interfaces via [SOAP](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client) or REST. Add an RPC client into your application and let it submit bugs from authorized users. How hard it is to make an RPC client will depend on the libraries for you application language, but typically it is not too difficult.

On a more specific note after reading your comments github allows use of a [REST interface](http://develop.github.com/p/issues.html) to work on issues. Integrating it into your application should be the matter of making a few http calls. Get the authentication right, use OAuth or similar single-sign-on mechanism.